# how to implement timeWindow() in Apache Flink's StreamTableEnvironment?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, stream, apache-flink, flink-sql

everyone,
I want to use flink time window in StreamTableEnvironment.

I have previously used the timeWindow(Time.seconds()) function with a dataStream that comes from a kafka topic.
For external issues I am converting this DataStream to DataTable and applying a SQL query with sqlQuery().

I want to do x second time window aggregations with SQL and then send it to another kafka topic

Data source:

```scala
    val stream = senv
      .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("flink", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
```

example of previous aggregation:

```scala
    val windowCounts = stream.keyBy("x").timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(5))
```

Current DataTable:

```scala
    val tableA = tableEnv.fromDataStream(parsed, 'user, 'product, 'amount)
```

In this part there should be a query that makes an aggregation each X time

```scala
    val result = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
          s"SELECT * FROM $tableA WHERE amount > 2".stripMargin)
```

more or less my aggregation will be count(y) OVER(PARTITION BY x)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Ververica's training for Flink SQL](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training/wiki) will help you with this. In includes some exercises/examples that cover just this kind of query in the section on [Querying Dynamic Tables with SQL](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training/wiki/Querying-Dynamic-Tables-with-SQL).

You'll have to establish the source of timing information for each event, which can be either processing time or event time, after which the query corresponding to `stream.keyBy("x").timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(5))` will be something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  x,
  TUMBLE_END(timestamp, INTERVAL '5' SECOND) AS t,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Events
GROUP BY
  x, TUMBLE(timestamp, INTERVAL '5' SECOND);
```

For details on how to work with time attributes, see the [Introduction to Time Attributes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#introduction-to-time-attributes).

And for more detailed documentation on windowing with Flink SQL see the docs on [Group Windows](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql/queries.html#group-windows).

Comment: Hi David, how can I use TUMBLE()  with this query... SELECT user, product, c_num
FROM (
  SELECT *,
     COUNT(user) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY proctime ASC) as c_num
  FROM Orders)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question to include the datastream api equivalent of what you want to compute with SQL?